# Является ли "может" вводным словом?

Tags: вводные-слова, пунктуация

Предложение: "И(,) может(,) что-нибудь выйдет."

Comment: @катя гднамлр, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Желательно: "И может, что нибудь выйдет".
Здесь вводное слово "может" обособляется вместе с присоединительным союзом "и". Парный вариант со сказуемым: И может что-нибудь выйти.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1)     Запятая обычно не ставится между присоединительным союзом и вводным словом,  так как  вводное слово тесно примыкает к союзу:

И действительно, мы больше не встречались. И кроме того, жизнь прекрасна. 
И в самом деле, Гуд-Гора курилась.
       А между тем, вы не совсем правы. А впрочем, как вам угодно; выстрел ваш остается за вами.
       Да кроме того, выяснились и другие подробности дела. 
       Но конечно, его трудно было переубедить.

2)  Запятая ставится как исключение, когда требуется смысловое выделение вводного слова:

И, как водится, вспоминали только одно хорошее. Но, к великой моей досаде, Швабрин, обыкновенно снисходительный, объявил, что песня моя нехороша.

ИЗ ПОЭЗИИ

Может быть, тот лес душа твоя,
Может быть, тот лес любовь моя,
Или, может быть, когда умрем
Мы в тот лес направимся вдвоем (Н. Гумилев).

Порой опять гармонией упьюсь,
Над вымыслом слезами обольюсь,
И может быть — на мой закат печальный
Блеснет любовь улыбкою прощальной (А. Пушкин).

И может быть, Вы бы даже
Меня не любили... Вы бы лежали - каким я
Вас люблю: ленивый,
Равнодушный, беспечный.
Изредка редкий треск Спички. Папироса горит и гаснет,
И долго-долго дрожит на её конце
Серым коротким столбиком пепел (М. Цветаева).

Ты не ушла. Но, может быть, 
В своем непостижимом строе 
Могла исчерпать и избыть 
Всё мной любимое, земное (А. Блок).